# Webview: window.close not working

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview

i have developed the android application with web view, i here load my sample html file which create the pop window,
but in android web view i dnt get the pop up instead of that pop window override the previous window .i using window.open to create pop up

if  i want close that window means i have to use window.close in my script but this not working in android web view
and also i gave the all permission

```
        WebSettings settings = Browser.getSettings();  
        settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
        Browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        Browser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        Browser.requestFocusFromTouch();
```

if i load the same page in browser it works properly.
is't possible to create pop in web view

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a pop-up with the new page, you will need to call back into java to create an android `dialog` view over the web view and load another web view into that. `window.close` will not work because that does not close the **`web view`**; it still remains open. Instead, you will need to call back into java again and `finish()` the activity that has the web view open. This would close the web view.